# How to get input from Json using generic class?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I want to write a generic class which inputs a Json file using the information in one field to determine what type of object is another field.

for example, `Widget` object which has 2 fields: `type` `data` and `data` fields depends on `type`

if `type` is "VideoPlayer", `data` should have "Name" & "Video" and if `type` is "Camera",`data` should have "Address" & "Input"

```
public class Widget<T> {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data<T> data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of the class Widget set the variable type and create a if/else if and depending the value, call the constructor `Data<VideoPlayer>` or `Data<Camera>`.

```
public Widget(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    if(type.equals("VideoPlayer")){ this.data = new Data<VideoPlayer>("Name","Video");}
    else if(type.equals("Camera")){ this.data = new Data<Camera>("Address", "Info");} 
}
```

Then inside the constructor of the class `Data<T>` you should have variables to set the info you want.